# Twisted Web serving Django project

Tags: python, django, twisted, wsgi, twisted.web

I have fresh Django project without any application just the defaults (e.g. admin)

My plan is to have **video chat** and **instant messaging** within my Django project.

**wsgi.py**

```
import os, sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('MY_DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MY_DJANGO_PROJECT.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I run my Twisted Web server within **MY_DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH** and the server start on port 8080.

`cd MY_DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH
twistd -n web --wsgi=MY_DJANG_PROJECT`

When I open it to the browser (http://127.0.0.1:8080/), I got an error

**WSGI application error**

`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.12-intel.egg/twisted/web/wsgi.py", line 315, in run
        appIterator = self.application(self.environ, self.startResponse)
    exceptions.TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Does anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to run Django using the Twisted server?

Comment: I would like to use Django for authentication for my Twisted application.

Answer (score 1):

I have able to serve my Django project within the Twisted using **twisted.web.wsgi.WSGIResource.**

Following the example [here.](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#serving-wsgi-applications)

**my_django_project.tac**

```
from twisted.web import server
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
from twisted.python.threadpool import ThreadPool
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.application import service, strports

# Create and start a thread pool
wsgiThreadPool = ThreadPool()
wsgiThreadPool.start()

# ensuring that it will be stopped when the reactor shuts down
reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('after', 'shutdown', wsgiThreadPool.stop)

import sys
sys.path.append('MY_DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH')
from MY_DJANGO_PROJECT import wsgi

# Create the WSGI resource
wsgiAppAsResource = WSGIResource(reactor, wsgiThreadPool, 
wsgi.application)

# Hooks for twisted
application = service.Application('My Django Project')
server = strports.service('tcp:8080', server.Site(wsgiAppAsResource))
server.setServiceParent(application)
```